# Is this one hot encoded?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

example 1 :

```
a = [['w1' , 'w3'] , ['w2' , 'w4']]

df=pd.DataFrame({'a': a })
print(df)

mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer()
print(np.array(mlb.fit_transform(df['a'].as_matrix())))
```

renders :

```
          a
0  [w1, w3]
1  [w2, w4]
[[1 0 1 0]
 [0 1 0 1]]
```

---

example 2 :

```
a = ['w1 w2' , 'w1 w3']

df=pd.DataFrame({'a': a })
print(df)

mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer()
print(np.array(mlb.fit_transform(df['a'].as_matrix())))
```

renders :

```
   a
0  w1 w2
1  w1 w3
[[1 1 1 0 1]
 [1 1 0 1 1]]
```

example 1 appears to one hot encode the dataframe at word level. What is example 2 computing ? It also appears to be one hot encoding but is not at word level ? I initially thought it was at character level but dataframe contains characters `1,2,3,w` , 4 characters but each array element :

```
[[1 1 1 0 1]
 [1 1 0 1 1]]
```

Is 5 characters in length.

Above code utilizes `MultiLabelBinarizer` http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MultiLabelBinarizer.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think your example 2 is in letter level

```
df['a'].as_matrix()
array(['w1 w2', 'w1 w3'], dtype=object)
```

Each letter including white space will convert to one hot key, thus there is five

Answer (score 1):

MultilabelBinarizer expects an iterable of iterables to be supplied as `y` as specified [in documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MultiLabelBinarizer.html#sklearn.preprocessing.MultiLabelBinarizer.fit)

Now, it doesn't check the type of supplied values but directly uses `itertools.chain.from_iterable` to find the elements.

From the [source code](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/a24c8b46/sklearn/preprocessing/label.py#L682):

```
classes = sorted(set(itertools.chain.from_iterable(y)))
```

So when you supply a list of words, the output classes will be `'characters'` in that word.

```
import itertools

# Single word
classes = set(itertools.chain.from_iterable('word'))
print(classes)
Output: {'d', 'o', 'r', 'w'}

# List of words
classes = set(itertools.chain.from_iterable(['word1', 'word2']))
print(classes)
Output: {'1', '2', 'd', 'o', 'r', 'w'}

# List of list of words
classes = set(itertools.chain.from_iterable([['word1', 'word2'], ['word3']]))
print(classes)
Output: {'word1', 'word2', 'word3'}
```